# Why has my drive space increased by 10GB?

Tags: windows-8.1, disk-space

My hard drive space has mysteriously increased by 10GB. I haven't uninstalled anything. I know of the pagefile but could it account for 10GB? Prior to this, my laptop was off and I had removed the battery for at least 2 hours.

Edit:

- I am using Windows 8.1 pro
- I use the laptop for light tasks e.g. web browsing, watching videos, working on school reports
- I hadn't installed any updated during my last session.

Comment: Did you deleted the recovery drive by any chance?

Comment: Windows continuously adds and removes updates from the `WinSxS` folder to maintain its ability to remove those updates.  This means the amount of space Windows uses to do this can increase or decrease by large amounts.  You should of course verify it wasn't the page file.

Comment: Your question, in its current form cannot be answered properly. There just isn't enough information to come up with a definitive answer. There can be any number of reasons why the drive space was reclaimed. Deletion of old restore points, cache cleanup, etc. If I were you, I'd just be glad to see 10 extra gigabytes of free storage space.

Comment: Jacob: I did not delete anything. I had 174GB, shut down, the laptop stayed off with the battery removed for a little more than 2 hours and when I turned it back on I had 185GB. Vinayak: I'm not regretting the extra space. Ramhound: I know space fluctuates but I've never seen it change by this much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the nebulous and insufficient data provided in your question, I believe the cause to be that your laptop was previously the victim of hackers.  They have recently decided they no longer need your PII and have removed 10g worth of hacking related files from this laptop.

You could prove this hypothesis wrong by including greater details of logs, etc. however I would guess that we may never know.  As Vinayak commented, the range of options, actions and configurations are too numerous.

For instance, is this a Windows OS machine?  Did it recently complete an update cycle?  was it recently rebooted for the first time after many hibernation sessions?  Did you delete an MS Office document you had been working on for many versions (which contained lots and lots of hidden content ... like, say, oh, a few Jpegs) ?

As you can see, the combination of options precludes any serious response to the question.  Hence, hackers is my current most viable answer.

Comment: To be safe, full format and reinstall. That'll solve the problem.

Comment: done and &^$%&*^....___

Comment: This answer may be amusing to some but it does not really answer the question.

Comment: “A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of feeble minds”